# Найти наибольшие последовательности идущих подряд чисел, которые увеличиваются

Tags: python, алгоритм

Имеется массив с числами `data = [2,3,4,45,6765,-99,-1,1,1,2,3,10,22,33,44,12,1,33,42,51,666,99,100,34,33,-99,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]`
нужно найти **последовательности идущих подряд чисел** **-99,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14** у меня есть код который я написал на python (да он страшен)))) но он работает, но с массивами где больше миллиона чисел он будет работать вечно).
Собственно сам код

```
data = [2,3,4,45,6765,-99,-1,1,1,2,3,10,22,33,44,12,1,33,42,51,666,99,100,34,33,-99,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]
res = []
while len(data) > len(res):
    temp_arr = []
    temp_arr.append(data[0])
    del data[0]
    for i in data:
        if i > temp_arr[-1]:
            temp_arr.append(i)
        else:
            del(data[:len(temp_arr) -1])
            break
    if len(temp_arr) > len(res):
        res = temp_arr
        temp_arr = []
print(res)
```

Я только учусь и еще не дружу с алгоритмами. Буду рад любой помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [2,3,4,45,6765,-99,-1,1,1,2,3,10,22,33,44,12,1,33,42,51,666,99,100,34,33,-99,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14,12,1,2,3,4,5,6]

arr = [[data[0]]]
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i - 1] > data[i]:
        arr.append([])
    arr[-1].append(data[i])

print(max(arr, key = len))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы нашел ответ за один проход. Код на C#, так как не знаю python, но суть я думаю ясна

```
var data = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 45, 6765, -99, -1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 22, 33, 44, 12, 1, 33, 
                   42, 51, 666, 99, 100, 34, 33, -99, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
                    9, 12, 13, 14, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var start = 0;
var end = 0;

int currentIndex = 0; 

while(currentIndex < data.Length-1)
{   
    var currentStart = currentIndex;    
    while(currentIndex < data.Length-1 && data[currentIndex] < data[currentIndex+1])
           currentIndex++;

    if (currentIndex - currentStart > end - start) (start, end) = (currentStart, currentIndex);

    while (currentIndex < data.Length - 1 && data[currentIndex] >= data[currentIndex + 1]) 
           currentIndex++;              
}   

for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)  
    Console.WriteLine(data[i]);
```

Результат

```
-99
-1
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
12
13
14
```

UPD: [перевод](https://tio.run/##jVDLboMwEDzHXzHHIIyEAyGFltx77hFxQIUkliIncl21/Xq6tlFjRF/Isped8eyMrx/mdFHZOPad6VCj2XBkHDmtLUexK2hPypI2weGXZ4iUKltaNtHFxoH2l2H55QRvCS@KgsPqiZQEstzf@JqQBhMIsxY4dhx3/DtRlNNc6@fmYXa9ZezFdNpQtpQNqncne37VelDmUfXDu@@8neR5wKz/gPOg1vZhokRUzsCEP02KIf3e4o70lxQ6smHrJuS0RFo0Y9FWYfKZaFxDMIfKwxxJ5kb3sMETuIfweitXc/gXCdl8JsX@kYiUf8y0r5ddxKBY@DXXDWKMHS4aElJBd@o4rAPrpBRVbHXVUhlnppFtNI6f) кода на python

```
data = [2, 3, 4, 45, 6765, -99, -1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 10, 22, 33, 44, 12, 1, 33, 
                   42, 51, 666, 99, 100, 34, 33, -99, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
                    9, 12, 13, 14, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

start = 0
end = 0

currentIndex = 0

while currentIndex < len(data)-1:
    currentStart = currentIndex;    
    while currentIndex < len(data)-1 and data[currentIndex] < data[currentIndex+1]:
           currentIndex += 1

    if currentIndex - currentStart > end - start:
        start, end = currentStart, currentIndex

    while currentIndex < len(data) - 1 and data[currentIndex] >= data[currentIndex + 1]: 
           currentIndex += 1          


for i in range(start, end + 1):
    print(data[i])
```

Comment: Ваш код на python https://tio.run/##jVDLboMwEDzHXzHHIIyEAyGFltx77hFxQIUkliIncl21/Xq6tlFjRF/Isped8eyMrx/mdFHZOPad6VCj2XBkHDmtLUexK2hPypI2weGXZ4iUKltaNtHFxoH2l2H55QRvCS@KgsPqiZQEstzf@JqQBhMIsxY4dhx3/DtRlNNc6@fmYXa9ZezFdNpQtpQNqncne37VelDmUfXDu@@8neR5wKz/gPOg1vZhokRUzsCEP02KIf3e4o70lxQ6smHrJuS0RFo0Y9FWYfKZaFxDMIfKwxxJ5kb3sMETuIfweitXc/gXCdl8JsX@kYiUf8y0r5ddxKBY@DXXDWKMHS4aElJBd@o4rAPrpBRVbHXVUhlnppFtNI6f

Comment: @Danis спасибо, добавил в ответ.